# Почему неправильно считается номер столбца?

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно найти максимальный элемент каждой строки массива, вывести его на экран, а также вывести номер строки и столбца.

```
int a, b;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        if (mas[i][j] > max)
            max = mas[i][j];
            a = i;
            b = j;
        }
    cout <<"максимальный элемент="<< max << "\n ";
    cout <<"номер строки="<<a<< "\n ";
    cout <<"номер столбца="<< b<< "\n";
}
```

[image: неправильно отображается номер столбца]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум, у вас неверная нумерация - в C/C++ элементы матрицы нумеруются с нуля.

Во-вторых, по-моему, вы скобки не так расставили...

Вобщем, смотрите, разбирайтесь...

```
int main()
{

    const int n = 5;
    int mas[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            mas[i][j] = rand()%20 - 10;
            cout << setw(6) << mas[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int max = mas[i][0];
        int idx = 0;
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mas[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = mas[i][j];
                idx = j;
            }
        }
        cout << "В строке " << i << " максимальный элемент "
             << max << " находится в столбце" << idx <<"\n";
    }
}
```